What is meant by "relative change" in the context of power laws?
I've encountered several definitions of a power law relationship that reference the notion of "relative change." For example, the Wikipedia entry states:
"A power law is a relationship in which a relative change in one quantity gives rise to a proportional relative change in the other quantity, independent of the initial size of those quantities."
I'm confused about what "relative change" specifically means in this context.
I've typically seen relative change defined as:
$$ \text{Relative change} = \frac{\text{Absolute change}}{\text{Reference value}} $$
However, using this definition, I'm having trouble reconciling it with the behavior of power law relationships. Does "relative change" here simply refer to a multiplicative factor (e.g., when we double the input, the response quadruples)? Or is it something else entirely?

Here, relative change is $\text{final value}/\text{starting value}$.  So change is measured relative to the initial value.  Similar phrasing " has increased by 10% over 2023".  The "10%" is ten percent of the starting value.

Algebraically, a power-law relationship between variables $x,y$ is defined as $y=Ax^r$ for some exponent $r$. If the values change from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$, your definition of relative change in $y$ yields
$$
\frac{\Delta y}{y_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{y_1}
=\frac{Ax_2^r-Ax_1^r}{Ax_1^r}
=\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)^r-1
$$
At the same time, the definition of relative change in $x$ yields
$$\frac{\Delta x}{x_1}=\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_1}\implies \frac{\Delta y}{y_1}=\left(1+\frac{\Delta x}{x_1}\right)^r-1$$
Thus the relative change in $y$ is a function of the relative change in $x$, but it is seemingly not a proportional relationship. However, if the relative change in $x$ is small, then we can approximate this relationship (via the binomial theorem) as
$$\frac{\Delta y}{y_1}\approx r \frac{\Delta x}{x_1}$$
which is indeed a proportional relationship. So the quoted remarks about power law relationships are valid for small relative changes.
